# Phpfox error in shorturl

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, phpfox

after i enabled shorturl in php .. i am getting 404 error ..
my htaccess is

```
######################################
## [PHPFOX_HEADER]
##
## @copyright       [PHPFOX_COPYRIGHT]
## @author          Raymond Benc
## @package         PhpFox
## @version         $Id: htaccess.txt 4580 2012-07-31 15:19:24Z Raymond_Benc $
######################################

# Options -Indexes
# Header unset Pragma
# FileETag None
# Header unset ETag

# URL Rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #
    #  Full path to your site
    #
    RewriteBase /

    # Rename Photo Names
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)_([0-9]*?)\.(.*)$ file/pic/photo/$1/$2/$3_$5.$6
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]{32}+)\-(.*?)\.(.*)$ file/pic/photo/$1/$2/$3.$5 

    #
    #  Rules
    #
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?do=/$1

    # Image Access Protection
    # RewriteRule ^file/pic/photo/(.*)\.(.*)$ static/image.php?file=$1&ext=$2
</IfModule>

# Modify Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Cache files
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 20 Apr 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>

    # Cache JavaScript & CSS
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 20 Apr 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
        Header unset Last-Modified
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Compress JavaScript & CSS
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

and i have changed htaccess.txt to .htaccess
and at `/include/setting/server.sett.php`
i have changed `$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '2';` to `$_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = '1';`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that `mod_rewrite` is activated in your web server